# How or what--------like?

Tags: word-choice

> 1 How was the weather yesterday?
>   2 What was the weather like yesterday?

and

> 3 How was the bride?
>   4 what was the bride like?

Are the two pairs of sentences correct? Is there any difference in meaning?

Comment: I don't why a question is downvoted.

Comment: You might get fewer downvotes if your questions aren't so sloppily-formatted. There are some formatting tips in our [Contributor's Guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners/4799#4799) as well as at other places on meta, like [this best practices question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3340). Also, if you hover over the downvote button, you'll discover it says "This question shows no research effort" – certainly the case here. See [_Details, Please_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both pairs are grammatically correct, but there can be, sometimes, a huge difference in meaning.

Generally:

> **How** was the bride?
>   Question about the bride's **condition**, as in, her welfare. Possible answer would be: *The bride was so excited with her big day that she cried throughout the whole ceremony.*
>   **What** was the bride **like**?
>   Question about the bride's **description**. Possible answer would be: *The bride was very beautiful. She was wearing a long white dress, and dyed her hair in a red shade.*

For the bride questions, the difference is clear. For the weather example, however, both phrases actually mean the same: if the weather was good or bad on that day.

Comment: *There **can be** a [sometimes, huge] difference in meaning*, not ***is***.

Comment: Nice! I changed the text while I wrote, and that part went unnoticed. Thanks!

Comment: I do not know why a question of this kind is down voted when the answer is upvoted three times includingme?